# changing the label of radio button to the fields of access

Tags: java, ms-access, radio-button

i want to change the label of the radio button to the fields of the access database.acess have 5 fields.i want to retrieve the five fields of the access database to the five radio buttons   of java.howerver my gui is showing error.please help

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.sql.*;

public class CreateRadioButton11 extends JApplet {

    JFrame jtfMainFrame;
    JButton getAccountButton, lastButton, firstButton, gotoButton, previousButton, nextButton;
    JTextField jtfInput;
    static JRadioButton[] choice = new JRadioButton[5];

    public CreateRadioButton11() {

        jtfMainFrame = new JFrame("Online Examination");
        jtfMainFrame.setSize(800, 500);
        jtfMainFrame.setLocation(200, 150);
        jtfMainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        nextButton = new JButton(">");
        previousButton = new JButton("<");
        lastButton = new JButton(">|");
        firstButton = new JButton("|<");
        gotoButton = new JButton("Goto");
        jtfInput = new JTextField(20);
        gotoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtfInput.setText("Button 1!");
            }
        });
        getAccountButton = new JButton("Finish");
        panel.add(jtfInput);
        panel.add(getAccountButton);
        panel.add(previousButton);
        panel.add(nextButton);
        panel.add(lastButton);
        panel.add(firstButton);
        panel.add(gotoButton);

        JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("a.");
        aLabel.setOpaque(true);
        aLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        aLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);


        JLabel bLabel = new JLabel("b.");
        bLabel.setOpaque(true);
        bLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        bLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JLabel cLabel = new JLabel("c.");
        cLabel.setOpaque(true);
        cLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        cLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JLabel dLabel = new JLabel("d.");
        dLabel.setOpaque(true);
        dLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        dLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        JLabel eLabel = new JLabel("e.");
        eLabel.setOpaque(true);
        eLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        eLabel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        choice[0] = new JRadioButton("a");
        choice[0].setBackground(Color.red);
        choice[1] = new JRadioButton("b");
        choice[1].setBackground(Color.red);
        choice[2] = new JRadioButton("c");
        choice[2].setBackground(Color.red);
        choice[3] = new JRadioButton("d");
        choice[3].setBackground(Color.red);
        choice[4] = new JRadioButton("e");
        choice[4].setBackground(Color.red);

        ButtonGroup bGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            bGroup.add(choice[i]);
        }

        JPanel panEast = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        jtfMainFrame.setContentPane(panEast);
        JPanel panlabels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JPanel pancontrols = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panEast.add(panlabels, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panEast.add(pancontrols, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panlabels.add(aLabel);
        pancontrols.add(choice[0]);
        panlabels.add(bLabel);
        pancontrols.add(choice[1]);
        panlabels.add(cLabel);
        pancontrols.add(choice[2]);
        panlabels.add(dLabel);
        pancontrols.add(choice[3]);
        panlabels.add(eLabel);
        pancontrols.add(choice[4]);
        panEast.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Select your answer"));
        panel.add("West", panEast);
        Container contentPane = jtfMainFrame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(panEast, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jtfMainFrame.add(panel);
        jtfMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtfMainFrame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateRadioButton11 r = new CreateRadioButton11();
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            String dataSourceName = "access";
            String dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "", "");

            Statement s = con.createStatement();
            s.execute("create table TEST12345 ( column_name integer )");
            s.execute("insert into TEST12345 values(1)");
            s.execute("select column_name from TEST12345");
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            if (rs != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Data from column_name: " + rs.getString(1));
                }
            }
            choice[0].setText(rs.getString(1));
            s.execute("drop table TEST12345");
            s.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + err);
        }
    }
}
```

i'm getting the error as:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
        at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
        at CreateRadioButton11.<init>(CreateRadioButton11.java:172)
        at CreateRadioButton11.main(CreateRadioButton11.java:190)
```

Comment: *"i want..'*  I want a pony.  And an ice-cream.  A nice, big ice-cream.  Now where done discussing our innermost desires, did you have a question?  2 Notes. 1)  Please fix your shift key and apply it to the start of every sentence.  2)  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you have a question??

Comment: i don't know how to retrieve access data into radiobutton.will u explain it

Comment: What did you try to a) retrieve the data from the access database and b) to set the radio button values?

Comment: Btw, I asked my friend google for "Java read access database" and it told me a lot of things ... :)

Comment: Are you asking how to a) Read the data from Access  and b) How to assign this data to the radio button labels?  Have you ever read data from an Access database before? If you have, the explanation will be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if youre asking this, the question is a little hard to understand,

See this [tutorial](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=2691&lngWId=2) to learn how to get values from databases, and then

to change the *label* of the radiobutton,get the required value/label_name from the database and you can use [setText(name_you_retrieved_from_db)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29) to set the button's text.